# Zendesk Update Ticket with several comments

Tags: javascript, json, zendesk

I am trying to update a ticket in Zendesk through their API with several comments. Apparently, it seems that I am using a wrong format for that, as the comments do not appear in my Zendesk dashboard...

I am using the following format (JSON):

```
{
      "ticket" : {
        "external_id":      externalID,
        "created_at":       incomingTicket.startDate,
        "updated_at":       incomingTicket.lastModificationDate,
        "type":             lType,
        "subject":          incomingTicket.topic,
        "description":      incomingTicket.description,
        "priority":         lPriority,
        "status":           lStatus,
        "comments":         [{"id": 3456, "body": "First comment Fix"}, {"id": 3457, "body": "Second Command Fix"}],
        "due_at":           incomingTicket.endDate,
        "tags":             [incomingTicket.label]
      }
    };
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` key isn't needed when creating a comment; the comment will automatically be assigned an id when you create it. It's actually an id of a ticket event, which you can access using the audit API: https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/ticket_audits#audit-events

Removing the `id` key should solve the issue for submitting a single comment at a time, like so:

```
{
      "ticket" : {
        "external_id":      externalID,
        "created_at":       incomingTicket.startDate,
        "updated_at":       incomingTicket.lastModificationDate,
        "type":             lType,
        "subject":          incomingTicket.topic,
        "description":      incomingTicket.description,
        "priority":         lPriority,
        "status":           lStatus,
        "comments":         {"body": "First comment Fix"},
        "due_at":           incomingTicket.endDate,
        "tags":             [incomingTicket.label]
      }
    };
```

Additionally, (I'm fairly sure) the `comments` key won't accept an array of comments for a single ticket update, so you'll need to make multiple calls for each comment (i.e., a single ticket update for each comment).